# How would I deal with spacing between words in remote JSON via React

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I'm having problems retrieving my data, I think because there are spaces in the JSON between the words. What is a good way of dealing with that so that I can use the JSON properly? I'm trying to loop through each of the games and get the id out of them but I think the "NCAA Division I" is messing it up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class GameList extends Component {

    state = { games: [] };

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://sportstakehouse.islandshore.net/dbdata/gameday/division')
        .then(response => this.setState({games: response.data}));
    }

    renderGames() {
        return this.state.games.map(game => <Text>{game.id}</Text>)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.renderGames}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default GameList;
```

That's my react code, I'm trying to get each game id out of this:

```
{
NCAA Division I: [
{
id: "4966",
api_id: "0a647d19-7150-4c66-92f1-f4f3fe9cd45d",
status: "scheduled",
scheduled: "2018-02-22 18:00:00",
conference_game: true,
game_time_date: "2018-02-22",
game_time_hour: "6:00pm",
home_team: {
id: "647",
api-id: "c851131a-5ecd-4670-81bc-b40f4837dd65",
name: "Owls",
alias: "FAU",
market: "Florida Atlantic",
conference-id: "74",
color-primary: "004B85",
color-secondary: "bb2f4c"
},
away_team: {
id: "646",
api-id: "bb384635-c3a0-459a-8f13-fcd7177313e5",
name: "Owls",
alias: "RICE",
market: "Rice",
conference-id: "74",
color-primary: "003D7D",
color-secondary: "d1d5d8"
},
venue: "FAU Arena",
broadcast_network: "",
broadcast_internet: "",
home_team_conference: "Conference USA",
away_team_conference: "Conference USA",
home_team_division: "NCAA Division I",
away_team_division: "NCAA Division I",
total_points_bet: 0,
total_points_bet_on_hometeam: 0,
total_points_bet_on_awayteam: 0,
featured: true
},
{
id: "4967",
api_id: "3c00c7ad-eaa7-4611-ba38-306e6d358332",
status: "scheduled",
scheduled: "2018-02-22 18:00:00",
conference_game: true,
game_time_date: "2018-02-22",
game_time_hour: "6:00pm",
home_team: {
id: "638",
api-id: "58d8baa3-7624-4b21-a47f-a23df2bf8859",
name: "Thundering Herd",
alias: "MRSH",
market: "Marshall",
conference-id: "74",
color-primary: "186329",
color-secondary: "be854c"
},
away_team: {
id: "648",
api-id: "ce967953-5c50-4220-87b2-99acb9606e84",
name: "Monarchs",
alias: "ODU",
market: "Old Dominion",
conference-id: "74",
color-primary: "00507d",
color-secondary: "a1d2f1"
},
venue: "Cam Henderson Center",
broadcast_network: "STADIUM",
broadcast_internet: "",
home_team_conference: "Conference USA",
away_team_conference: "Conference USA",
home_team_division: "NCAA Division I",
away_team_division: "NCAA Division I",
total_points_bet: 0,
total_points_bet_on_hometeam: 0,
total_points_bet_on_awayteam: 0,
featured: false
},
```

Comment: You should really surround that "NCAA Division I" with double quotes. How are you generating thar JSON data?

Comment: @Miguel my backend dev is currently generating it, but he's away right now and I can't have him fix the issue.

Comment: What does `response` give you when you console it?

Comment: @JamieHutber it says TypeError: this.state.games.map is not a function

Comment: No, you need to do it before it does the `map` so please update your `then(response => this.setState({games: response.data}));` to output `response`

Comment: @JamieHutber so instead of response.data just response?

Comment: then(response => {console.info(response); return this.setState({games: response.data}}));

Comment: @JamieHutber  {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: undefined, headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

Comment: ok now do `response.data`

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed something... Please replace this function: `    renderGames() {
console.info(this.state); and remove the other `console.log`
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're are correct, the response you have given is not valid JSON. For many reasons not just that you have spaces in your keys.

To fix this you will need to edit where you are generating the data from, namely you will need to make the response valid:

```
{
     "NCAA Division I": [
        {
            "id: "4966",
            "api_id": "0a647d19-7150-4c66-92f1-f4f3fe9cd45d",
            "status": "scheduled",
            "scheduled": "2018-02-22 18:00:00",
            "conference_game": true,
            "game_time_date": "2018-02-22",
            "game_time_hour": "6:00pm",
            "home_team": {
                "id": "647",
                "api-id": "c851131a-5ecd-4670-81bc-b40f4837dd65",
                "name": "Owls",
                "alias": "FAU",
                "market": "Florida Atlantic",
                "conference-id": "74",
                "color-primary": "004B85",
                "color-secondary": "bb2f4c"
                ......
    }
}
```

However, having spaces in an object (not JSON) is perfectly valid as your keys would just be strings so:

```
const data = {
    'NCAA DIVISION I': []
}
```

Would be valid and you could interact with this data perfectly easily. Doing `maps, filters` etc

[**Edit**]

I just realised you haven't set a constructor on your class, this means you have no internal state:

```
class GameList extends Component {
     construtor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {};
     }
     ....
}
```

Comment: How am I able to use this on my web app if it's not valid JSON?

Comment: You should still get the response back, please check `response` by console.log and show output in ur question

Comment: babel will transpile state into a constructor even if you don't put one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to map over an object, it's not an array. If you don't need the key, then you can set this.state.games to the values of what's being returned.

```
axios.get('https://sportstakehouse.islandshore.net/dbdata/gameday/division')
        .then(response => this.setState({ games: Object.values(response.data) }));
```